# Regex to validate International email

Tags: java, javascript, regex

Not sure if there is a solution available but not able to find. So asking it again.

I am writing an email validator. This should validate all well formed email(This is just one level of validation to check the email is well formed). Now as my code is an international code so i should support non latin characters also. How do i write the most efficient Regex for that?

International Emails: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_email

Some example emails:

1. 伊昭傑@郵件.商務
2. राम@मोहन.ईन्फो
3. юзер@екзампл.ком
4. θσερ@εχαμπλε.ψομ

It should be able to validate all the above formats

Comment: `[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+`. (Confirmed in www.regexpal.com to match all four of those emails exactly.) Don't get any more complex than that - the only way to find out an email address is REALLY correct is to send it an email, anyway, so be permissive.

Comment: Instead of making an email regex that says what is authorized (as we usually do for English characters), make a regex that says what is forbidden (eg `x@.xyz`, `x@a..b`, `x@-y`, `x@y-`, `x@a--b`, etc...

Comment: I agree with ring0.  The full legal form of what can be an email address can't really be validated with a regex - it takes more of a real parser.  I'd suggest that you just weed out the most common omissions.

Comment: @Patashu nice option but it will pass emails like x@a..b which is again invalid

Comment: @KD. Even if an email is syntactically valid, it might be invalid anyway (the email does not exist) - so why do you need such a strict regex, if a regex alone will not confirm email addresses?

Comment: it mostly to stop users from mistyping / intentionally putting wrong data and there are also other need in this implementation which i wont be able to provide all details.

Comment: Check out my answer at this link -> [RegEx using Unicode][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774413/multilingual-email-address-validation-with-jquery-and-regex/23875597#23875597

Answer (score 9):

The reason why email validation through regexp is so lax is because it's not efficient. There *is* a spec for email address syntax, but [the regexp to check it is so long, it's impractical](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html). Besides, email providers are more strict in their implementation of the syntax than the actual spec. An email might be considered valid as the spec says it is, but invalid according to the provider.

That's also the reason why activation emails exist, because the only way to check if an email is valid, existing and currently in use is to send it something, usually a unique activation code or link. Only when that unique activation code or link, only sent to that email, is used will the email be considered valid.

Until then, consider a more lax approach in validating emails, checking if the username, the `@` and the domain parts. Besides, why would one sign up using a false email anyway? If they did, they wouldn't get the activation link, and can't proceed creating the account.

Comment: This is more an implementation to check if the email is well formed before submitting/putting into what ever business logic it will go through. This is nothing to do with sign up

Comment: @KD. in the link above explains a RegExp that's 99% perfect as well as the specification. Read on.

Comment: Ya thats right. The last regex is really huge but works well. But problem is i need one which even supports international emails like say 伊昭傑@郵件.商務

Answer (score 4):

@Patashu Thanks a lot. I've improved your regex a bit and now it's absolutely suits my needs:

```
^([^@\s\."'\(\)\[\]\{\}\\/,:;]+\.)*[^@\s\."'\(\)\[\]\{\}\\/,:;]+@[^@\s\."'\(\)\[\]\{\}\\/,:;]+(\.[^@\s\."'\(\)\[\]\{\}\\/,:;]+)+$
```

Comment: This is a great improvement, but there is at least one problem with it, in that you have excluded the apostrophe (`'`) as a valid character from the local part. Many real world names (for example, Irish surnames) frequently include apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Java, this one works quite well for me.

```
"^[\\p{L}\\p{N}\\._%+-]+@[\\p{L}\\p{N}\\.\\-]+\\.[\\p{L}]{2,}$"
```

It does not allow IP's after the @ but most valid email in the from of `xxx@xxx.TDL` could be validated with it.
`\p{L}` validates UTF-Letters and `\p{N}` validates UTF-Numbers. You can check [this doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more information.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me using Python if you do not have special letters,characters but have dashes(-), numbers, both in the domain and in the username. This also matches if you have country extensions.

[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z-]+.(com|edu|net)(.([a-z]+))*